# What will be the values of a, b, c?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, blocking, nonblocking

Mixing blocking and non-blocking is not recommended as I understand. But if it indeed exists, what will be the values of a, b, c?

```
module TB; 
reg a, b, c;
initial begin 
  a = 3;
  b = 4;
  $display ("a = %d, b = %d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
  c <=  a + b;
  $display ("a = %d, b = %d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
  a <= 10;
  b  <= 2;
  c = a + b;
  $display ("a = %d, b = %d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Did you get unexpected results when you tried to simulate this piece of code?  There are some free SystemVerilog online simulators like [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/) that you should be able to use.

Comment: you should be able to answer your question from the output of your program.  just simulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module TB; 
reg ***[2:0]*** a, b, c;
initial begin 
   a = 3;
   b = 4;
$display ("a = %d, b = %d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
c <=  a + b;
$display ("a = %d, b = %d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
a <= 10;
b  <= 2;
c = a + b;
$display ("a = %d, b = %d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
end
endmodule
```

a=3, b=4 and c=7

Timing Queue of Verilog is divided into four parts:
Active Region -> Inactive -> NBA -> Postponed
Blocking assignments gets evaluated and assign in the ACTIVE region along with $display(). While Nonblocking assignments get evaluated in the ACTIVE region and assign in the NON BLOCKING ASSIGNMENT(NBA) Region. Hence whatever updates made to the a,b,c wont get printed using display statement. You can use $monitor which gets executed in the postponed region.